# Set Live Wallpaper to the Android Lock Screen

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Since Android API Level `24` the methods to set the wallpaper accept a parameter to be possible to specify `which` wallpaper we want to set (`Lock` or `System`).

Unfortunately, I don't find a way to use it with `Live Wallpapers`. The methods available in the `WallpaperManager` class only support `images` or an `InputStreams`. They don't support `Live Wallpapers`.

Some `Samsung` devices accept the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, LiveWallpaperService.class));
intent.putExtra("SET_LOCKSCREEN_WALLPAPER", true);
```

But this does only work on some the devices.

There is any other method available to programatically set a `Live Wallpaper` to the `Lock Screen`?